# Ionic 2 & Cordova Map Plugin Marker drag issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using the cordova map plugin. I have added the marker & added the MARKER_DRAG_END event. Event also get fired but in promise I am not getting the new latlng of the marker. Can you please let me know how can we achieve this ?

```
this.map.addMarker({
            'position': location,
            'icon': 'green',
            'title': "Pickup Location",
            'draggable': true
            //,'animation': google.maps.Animation.DROP
          }, function(marker) {
            alert('addMarker callback started.');
            //this.addUpdateMarkerData('pickup',marker,location);                
            //marker.showInfoWindow();

              //Drag event of marker
              marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG_END, function(marker) {
                alert('GoogleMapsEvent MARKER_DRAG_END');
                marker.getPosition(function(latLng) {
                  alert('GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG_END Lat ~ '+latLng.lat() + ' And Long ~ '+latLng.lng())
                  //marker.setTitle(latLng.toUrlValue());
                  //marker.showInfoWindow();


                });
              });

          });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to subscribe to event listener to get the position data and getPOsition() returns promise

```
 marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG_END).subscribe(
                        data => {
                            marker.getPosition().then((LatLng) => {
                                alert('GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG_END Lat ~ '+latLng.lat() + ' And Long ~ '+latLng.lng())
                  //marker.setTitle(latLng.toUrlValue());
                  //marker.showInfoWindow();
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AishApp. I am struggling from last 2 days to achieve this. Your code work like charm.... Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help :)